# Fill in the NOT NULL columns of a table while using the INSERT INTO statement

Tags: oracle, select, insert, sqlplus

I'm working through a problem where I need to insert 135 rows into a recently created table with a select statement. I have a handful of NOT NULL constraints on that table and I don't understand how to alter my SELECT to insert the correct information.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE target_table_s1 START WITH 1001;

INSERT INTO target_table(colA,ColB,ColC,ColD,ColE)
target_table_s1.NEXTVAL,
(SELECT (colB,colC,ColD)
FROM source_table),
colE;
```

Where colA is a sequence number (to provide a primary key for the target_table) and colE basically just needs to be something simple like SYSDATE.

Any suggestions on how I can make this work? I know that what I've written above isn't going to work but it's the best way I can illustrate what I'm trying to accomplish. Do I need to find a way to put my sequence inside the select statement so it follows the proper "INSERT INTO SELECT" format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should just be using the `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` construct here:

```
INSERT INTO target_table (colA,ColB,ColC,ColD,ColE)
SELECT target_table_s1.NEXTVAL, ColB, ColC, ColD, SYSDATE
FROM source_table
```

I assume above that you want to insert the `SYSDATE` into column E.

Comment: So this is pretty much what I'm looking for and I've almost solved my problem. Maybe you can help me with the last little bit. Here's my new context:

Comment: INSERT INTO target_table(colA, colB, colC, colD, colE)

Comment: SELECT seq.NEXTVAL, f.colB, f.colC, f.colD, SYSDATE
FROM (SELECT colB, colC, colD FROM source_table);

How do I alias the source table as f? Do I just use  "FROM source_table f"? What if the from statement involves multiple tables?

(sorry, my comments keep submitting even when I haven't finished)

Comment: Yes, if you want to alias `source_table` then use `FROM source_table AS f`

Comment: This worked perfectly in my practical code. Accepted answer.